# How to change references to refer to a different property in a class automatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a class like so:

```
public class Properties
{
    public string property1 { get; set; }
    public string property2 { get; set; }
}
```

**property1** is referenced a number of times in a project but I need all of those references to refer to **property2** instead.

Without manually going through each reference, is there a more efficient way of updating all references to **property1** to refer to **property2**?

Comment: Just change property1 to property123 and fix it manually where you see the errors. I dont think you have referenced it 1000 times, so you should be finished faster than asking a question here and implementing a different solution.

Comment: It's hard to give better advice with this pseudo code.In general you should consider to use a dependency injection framework like StructureMap. Then you have just one place to change.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're talking about all property1, you can do what you want as long as you modify the definition of property1:

```
public string property1
{
    get { return property2; }
    set { property2 = value; }
}
```